# How to filter a Map Value using QueryDSL over Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I have a Java entity Person that contains a

```
Map<AddressType, Address>,
```

and i need to filter to person that contains an address on specific city.

How can i do this with QueryDSL?

I verified that QueryDSL contains a method called "containsValue", but i don't know how i can use it. If i already have the exactly object that i need, i can  simply put a

```
QPerson.person.addresses.containsValue(myAddress)
```

but this doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: I don't know QueryDSL but with JPQL/HQL id probably use something like `... JOIN person.addresses address WITH address.city = :param` (or just join and use a where-condition).

Comment: did you every figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example like this

```
query.from(person)
     .innerJoin(person.addresses, address).on(address.city...)
     .list(...)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with containsValue() instead of having to specify innerJoins, etc?

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to do is get a Predicate back to do this, rather than a full query.

Comment: Don't we have a solution without using innerJoin? I, too, need to get a predicate, not query, for Spring Data Jpa

Answer (score 0):

Have a try:

`JPAExpressions.selectFrom(address).where(address.city.eq("city"))`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.